# read csv file and filter specific columns in Lambda (Java8)

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, bufferedreader, filereader

Suppose I have some file having some data in comma separated format as below

```
TIMESTAMP,COUNTRYCODE,RESPONSETIME,FLAG

1544190995,US,500,Y
1723922044,GB,370,N
1711557214,US,750,Y
```

My requirement is, I want to read this file and filter data based on columns(TIMESTAMP and RESPONSETIME) and check whether the data is numeric or not.

**I have tried as below, but it did not work. Can some one assist me on the same ?**

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

rows = br.lines().map(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(DELIMITER))).filter(a -> a.equals("TIMESTAMP")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: what did you mean by it did not work?

Comment: did you try to makes it without lambda, because I see that the map return `ArrayList` then you use `.filter(a -> a.equals("TIMESTAMP"))` which is not logic `ArrayList` is not a `String` no?

Comment: I mean, it did not give me the expected outcome.
Expected Outcome:
It should return the boolean value 
->'true' -> If both the fields are numeric (TIMESTAMP and RESPONSETIME)
->'false' -> Either one the fields are non numeric (TIMESTAMP and RESPONSETIME))

Comment: Thanks. Cant we achieve with lamda. ?

Comment: No you can, can you please show us the result of `br.lines().forEach(System.out::println)`

Answer (score 2):

Currently, after the `map` operation, you have a `Stream<List<String>>`  and you're trying to compare that with a `String`, hence will never yield the expected outcome.

Now, to the solution; from what I can gather it seems that you want to retain the entire line if the `TIMESTAMP` and `RESPONSETIME` are valid integers.

One way to go about this is:

```
 List<String> rows = br.lines()
            .skip(1) // skip headers
            .map(s -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(s,s.split(DILIMETER)))
            .filter(a -> isInteger(a.getValue()[0]) && isInteger(a.getValue()[2]))
            .map(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and the `isInteger` function being defined as follows:

```
public static boolean isInteger(String input)
{
      if(input == null || input.trim().isEmpty()) return false;
      for (char c : input.toCharArray())
          if (!Character.isDigit(c)) return false;
      return true;
}
```

Another solution being is if you want to retrieve a `List<String[]>` where each array represents the individual data of each line then you can do:

```
List<String[]> rows = br.lines()
                .skip(1) // skip headers
                .map(s -> s.split(DILIMETER))
                .filter(a -> isInteger(a[0]) && isInteger(a[2]))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

*Note*, if the file being read only contains the data with no headers then there is no need to perform the `skip` operation.

Answer (score 1):

Presently this is what you doing :

1. read all lines that give : `List<String>`
2. You split it so that give you `String[]` and you convert it to `List<String>` (that is correct) but you are in a map so the result of the map is `Stream<List<String>>`
3. You filter and `a` is a `List`. You try to compare a `List` and a `String`. 
   Bip bip bop bop, problem!

Like @YCF_L said, try it without lambda..

Comment: the result of the map operation is `Stream<List<String>>` not `List<List<String>>`.

Comment: you are right! just realise it but you are too fast for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

the problem is you will just get a list full of "TIMESTAMP" which isn't useful. 
if the file format is always the same, meaning the order and number of headers, you can just skip the first line, then read each of the lines with the data and access just the columns with the data you want to validate. and it may be better to use a for or while loop so you can terminate early.

```
boolean allNumericData = true;
do{
   String[] row = br.nextLine().split(DELIMITER)
   if(!isNumeric(row[0])||!isNumeric(row[2])){
       allNumericData = false;
   }
}while(allNumericData ||br.nextRow = null)
```

if the headers can be different
then open the file read the first row to determine the index of the data required to validate, and do the same as above but with the found index. 
also this is pseudo code. you will need to do the validation and handling of fetching and null checking the next row

Answer (score 0):

You can as well use `flatMap` and later on filter only string containing digits:

```
List<String> timeAndResponse = br.lines()
        .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(",")))
        .filter(s -> s.chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In this case you are working with streams only:

`.flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(",")))` we take an individual line from the file, split it by `,` - take a stream from an intermediate array and finally call `flatMap`. This will give us `Stream<String>` where `String` is and individual string from original line `1544190995,US,500,Y`. After this point let's just leave only numeric string using filter. Finally let's collect everything to a `List`, which will contain the following values:

```
[1544190995, 500, 1723922044, 370, 1711557214, 750]
```

I hope this helps.